# How can a Java program detect that the MacOS machine is being shut down?

Tags: java, macos, daemon

I have a Java application that I want to be started on my Mac whenever I start the machine. The application should be shut down gracefully whenever the machine is shut down.

I added a shutdown hook in the main method:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new ShutdownHook(scheduler)));
```

`ShutdownHook` class looks like this:

```
public class ShutdownHook implements  Runnable {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Shutdown Hook");
    private final Scheduler scheduler;

    public ShutdownHook(Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.debug("Starting to shot down the application");
        try {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        } catch (final SchedulerException e) {
           LOGGER.error("An error occurred while trying to shut down the scheduler", e);
        }
        LOGGER.info("Exiting the shutdown hook");
    }
}
```

Then I built the application into an executable JAR and added it to the list of "Login items".

[image: "Users and Groups" window]

The application is started when I log in.

However, the shutdown hook is not executed when the machine shuts down.

**How can I make sure that when I shut down the machine using the menu item shown below, a running Java application detects that the machine is shutting down?**

[image: "Shutdown" menu item]

**Update 1:**

As far as I understand, one way to fix the error is to use `launchd` to start the Java program. I wrote the `plist` file below.

The next question is how to make sure that `launchd` runs the application described in that `plist` file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/XXXXXX/sw/wordcounter-daemon/error</string>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.dpisarenko.wordcounterdaemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
        <string>-jar</string>
        <string>/Users/XXXXXXX/sw/wordcounter-daemon/wordcounter-daemon-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It is not guaranteed that shutdown hooks will always run. if the OS gives a SIGKILL signal (kill -9 in Unix/Linux) or TerminateProcess (Windows), then the application is required to terminate immediately without honoring any clean up hook.

Comment: Just in case anybody is confused: a "shutdown hook" is a hook that is run before the _JVM_ is being shut down. It is unrelated to an OS shut down. Of course, the OS is free to orderly shut down all of its processes, including a running JVM, first. But when you register a shutdown hook in a Java program, it is about shutting down the program, you do not listen for OS shutdowns.

Answer (score 3):

Usually Unix-style systems will shutdown [a daemon process](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html) in two steps:

1. `SIGTERM` signal send to process
2. `SIGKILL` signal send to process if the process still runs after X seconds after point 1

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361723) explains how to configure `ExitTimeOut` value which controlls time between these two signals on MacOS.

The behaviour for non-daemon processes might be different and this might be the reason your process is not executing JVM shutdown hook. The JVM probably received `SIGKILL` and by design a user-space process can't handle this signal. Potentially you want to convert your process to a daemon.

Comment: Thanks. I created a `plist` file shown in *Update 1*. Can you please point me to a tutorial on how to make `launchd`/operating system use that file to start the Java application on startup?